# File download test in Symfony

Tags: file, symfony, testing, download, phpunit

I need to test if file will start download when user click on button.

Right now I'm clicking on download button "a.btn-info" via client and it just print text from file into PHPUnit console

```
$client->request('GET', $crawler->filter('a.btn-info')->attr('href'));
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply perform request with HEAD method like

```
$client->request('HEAD', $crawler->filter('a.btn-info')->attr('href'));
```

and check if response code is 200 and there is a "Content-Disposition: attachment" header.

It will mean that file exists and will be downloaded and not opened in browser.

Comment: Ok, my code looks now like this         
    
$crawler=$client->request('GET',$client->getContainer()->get('router')->generate('import'));
    $this->assertEquals(200,$client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());

    $client->request('HEAD', $crawler->filter('a.btn-info')->attr('href'));
    $this->assertEquals(200,$client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());

But I'm getting the same result. Can you help me also with Content-Disposition: attachment ? as I'm not sure how to deal with 
Thank you!

Comment: First of all - is link of a.btn-info element targeted to static file or to controller action that sends file back to the user?

Comment: link is targeted to a static .csv file